# How to create post on Yammer with bolded text in Python?

Tags: python, excel, yammer

I'd like to open excel to read text, then create a post on Yammer using this text. I know how to do it but i have one problem. I don't have any idea how to read bolded font. I want to create post using bold function. It doesn't work if i use bold on text in excel because i read it as a string.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I used bold generator and copied all letters. Then I swapping all letters on bolded.